# Line integral conservative vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $F(x; y) = (-g(t)y; g(t)x)$, where $t = x^{2} + y^{2}$ and $g(t)$ is a  function (of single variable)
which is differentiable (class $C^1$) for $t > 0$.

I have to calculate the line integral on the unit circle, $F \cdot dr$, counter clockwise.

How does the information that $g(t)$ is differentiable help us ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you may use Stokes theorem, for which differentiability is needed

Comment: thanks but we are not supposed to do that because we did not go through it yet , this is on the problem set of green's theorem , line integrals and conservative vector fields.

Comment: Then use Green's theorem with $\vec{r}=x\bar{i}+y\bar{j}$

Comment: Can you please show me how ? i got stuck when i did that , because i end up taking double integral of 2 g(t) witch depend on the function g .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. If $(x,y)$ is on the unit circle centred at the origin then
$$\mathbf{F}(x; y) = (-g(t)y; g(t)x)=g(1)(-y,x).$$
Hence
$$\int_{C}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=g(1)\int_0^{2\pi}\left(-\sin t,\cos t\right) \cdot\left(-\sin t,\cos t\right)dt.$$
P.S. If $g(1)\not=0$ then the vector field $\mathbf{F}$ is not conservative in a simply connected region which contains the origin.
To be conservative we need that 
$$-g'(t)t_y\cdot y-g(t)=(-g(t)y)_y=(g(t)x)_x=g'(t)t_x\cdot x+g(t)$$
that is $-g(t)=g'(t)t$ which implies $g(t)=\frac{C}{t}$.

Comment: brilliant answer in minimum steps!

Comment: Very elegent solution , can you give me a hint how to show that F is a conservative field in a simply connected region if and only if g(t) = k/t , k is constant. 
Thanks again

Comment: To be conservative you need that $(-g(t)y)_y=(g(t)x)_x$.

Comment: Thanks alot ! i did prove the implication but only for 1 direction , can you  please post to both ( no full solution just highlight ) so i can see if my argument is correct and see how to think about these questions .

Comment: I started with g(t) = k/t and showed that it is valid , but not knowing g (t) = k/t how would I proceed ? 
Thanks so much again

Comment: @Kasmir Khaan See my P.S.

Comment: I made an attempt on solving it but i failed now after i seen your solution it is clear ! forgot the inside derivative of t w.r.t x and y . at least I understand how to solve it now anyway. Thanks alot mate! :)

Comment: @Kasmir Khaan Well done!!